# Extracting the dispersion parameter in a GLM output

Tags: r, survey

From [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33432/dispersion-parameter-in-glm-output), a `svyglm` model's summary includes a line like

`(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 28.35031)`

If my linear model object is `my_lm`, how do I extract its dispersion parameter? Something like `my_lm$dispersion`. I am trying to extract this value as a variable, not just print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
fit2 <- glm( Sepal.Length ~ ., data=iris )
summary(fit2)$dispersion
[1] 0.09414226
```

Notice that the dispersion is in the summary object and not in the model object